# Mistakes while reading Quran

Tags: quran, quran-recitation

Asalamualikum
I made a mistake while reading Surah al-Kahf verse No. 92 and realised later after finishing the surah that the verse is repeated, and I made mistake without correcting them. What should I do in this situation ? Should I read the whole Surah once again or recite the verse correctly next time onwards

Please advise

Jazakallah

Comment: by mistake do you mean by tajweed mistakes?. if your mistake is done by ignorance or unintentional, then when you know what is right, continue doing it the right way. and what do you mean by the verse is repeated?. it may sound repeated in pronunciation but its differs a little bit it meaning as in verse 89 and 92 are referring to two separate incidents.in short, just recite it the correct way according to tajweed the next time,

Answer (score 0):

Ill try to answer in the best possible way while ensuring this site remains like a muslim peer support group and you do not get offended.
Allah sees everything today.That means the past, present and future. If you do a mistake you can learn from it and make corrections according to knowledge of the mistake at the time of mistake.There are like many pathways you can take. You can even start from scrath and try fixing the mistake.
Whatver you do, Allah is watching and he will compensate you, I beleive for every mistake you do.
Look at Allah's attributes and decide but be truthful.